# Java Initialize an int array in a constructor

Tags: java

I have a class and in that class I have this:

```
 //some code
 private int[] data = new int[3];
 //some code
```

Then in my constructor:

```
public Date(){
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = 0;
    data[2] = 0;
}
```

If I do this, everything is OK. Default data values are initialized but if I instead do this:

```
public Date(){
    int[] data = {0,0,0};
}
```

It says:

```
Local variable hides a field
```

Why?

What's the best way to initialize an array inside the constructor?

Comment: I hope you are aware of the concept of scope of variable? your variable `data` after `"//some code"` is having a scope of the entire class. while the variable `data` in the constructor is having a scope inside the constructor. and once the constructor is done, the variable will be destroyed. And also the `data` variable inside constructor hides the variable by same name in the class. This justifies the error `Local variable hides a field`

Answer (score 194, accepted):

```
private int[] data = new int[3];
```

This already initializes your array elements to 0. You don't need to repeat that again in the constructor.

In your constructor it should be:

```
data = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
```

Comment: Yes. This was the only way It allowed me. Putting just data; said that "its not a statement". Thanks

Comment: Can't he use `data=new int[3]` in defualt constructor `Date()`?

Answer (score 10):

You could either do:

```
public class Data {
    private int[] data;

    public Data() {
        data = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
    }
}
```

Which initializes `data` in the constructor, or:

```
public class Data {
    private int[] data = new int[]{0, 0, 0};

    public Data() {
        // data already initialised
    }
}
```

Which initializes `data` before the code in the constructor is executed.

Comment: I have to put data = new int[] {0,0,0}; inside the constructor. If I initialize before the code in the constructor putting just data; inside the constructor gave me "not a statement" error

Comment: if there are more than million elements in array.. you would like to use first code and change line `public Data() throws Error {` if `OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

why not simply

```
public Date(){
    data = new int[]{0,0,0};
}
```

the reason you got the error is because `int[] data = ...` declares a new variable and hides the field `data`

however it should be noted that the contents of the array are already initialized to 0 (the default value of `int`)

Answer (score 4):

This is because, in the constructor, you declared a local variable with the same name as an attribute.

To allocate an integer array which all elements are initialized to zero, write this in the constructor:

```
data = new int[3];
```

To allocate an integer array which has other initial values, put this code in the constructor:

```
int[] temp = {2, 3, 7};
data = temp;
```

or:

```
data = new int[] {2, 3, 7};
```

Answer (score 1):

in your constructor you are creating another int array:

```
 public Date(){
  int[] data = {0,0,0};
  }
```

Try this:

```
 data = {0,0,0};
```

NOTE: By the way you do NOT need to initialize your array elements if it is declared as an instance variable. Instance variables automatically get their default values, which for an integer array, the default values are all zeroes.

If you had locally  declared array though they you would need to initialize each element.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is not to write any initializing statements. This is because if you write 
`int a[]=new int[3]` then by default, in Java all the values of array i.e. `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` are initialized to `0`! Regarding the local variable hiding a field, post your entire code for us to come to conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that this will change the number of elements in the constructor.
That is...

```
public class Test
{
   int[] arr =new int[4];
   int n = arr.length;
   Test()
   { 
       arr = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
       n = arr.length;
   }
 }
```

In the Constructor, `int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` will compile successfully even though the limit is 4 because of the `new` keyword.
The final `n` value is 7.